# jmeter : connection reset -http client implementation 4

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am using jmeter 2.13 [latest version]. Running a loadtest on https web application with a load of 10000 users. I am using 40 [x250 users/LG] load generators for this. All are 8gb ram & quadcore processors & CentOS operated.
I am getting java.net.socket exception: connection reset issue.
I tried in both options using keep-alive checked & unchecked.
Done all the recommendations need to avoid this issue. Still I am getting the issue. Server is also not showing any issues/logs on reset.
Please help me in understanding the root cause for this issue & how can I avoid this issue.

Also I didn't quite understand the active threads overtime graph? Why the spikes in the graph? Does it mean the thread will connect again after reset? [I have used stop thread on error].

Comment: Similar question was answered this week [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31790434/2897748

Comment: yes... i have followed all the steps mentioned before posting this question.....still i am getting the errors

Comment: Maybe you're running out of available network sockets?

Answer (score 0):

Link given above by Dmitri T is very useful, may fix you problem. If it won't, you may want to consider switching to other HTTP Client implementation. I recently faced a strange issue (probably a bug in client v4), which disappeared afer downgrading client version.

Comment: unfortunately the solution didn't work in my case....downgrading means i have tried with java & httpIMpl4.....never checked with httpimpl3...you want me to give a try with that...