# Connection reset on heavy load using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to perform load 15000 concurrent requests on my application server(linux red hat) which has 16 core and 32 GB RAM through 2 jmeter server(windows server 2012) with configuration of 16 core and 32 GB RAM and getting this error "Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException/Non HTTP response message: Connection reset"

I've already followed this link related to configuration but couldn't find any solution [Java.net.SocketException connection reset error in .net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772952/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset-error-in-net-application)

First i was using single Jmeter server(Window server 2012) for 15000 request and i split this into two servers 7500 concurrent request each with configuration of 16 core and 32 GB RAM but getting same issue on  "Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException/Non HTTP response message: Connection reset"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a socket issue on your server end.
Go to /etc/security/limits.conf
and update soft limit to a higher value.

For example:

vi /etc/security/limits.conf
set ulimit of soft and hard to maximum count