# Server error when client accesses concurrently

Tags: java

Good afternoon ..
can anybody help me?
The following error below is occurring on the server, when many clients connect at the same time.
"java.net.SocketException: connection reset."
Does anyone know what this error is?

Comment: Possibly related: [java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62929)

Answer (score 0):

This could range from your server not having sufficient resources to take this load, to your code prematurely closing connections because of programming error.

Doing a quick lookup myself I see indeed something related to server configuration:

> [Connection reset on heavy load using jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059570/connection-reset-on-heavy-load-using-jmeter#answer-58061088)